# How can I quickly rename folders in tfs?

Tags: tfs

I have around 200 folders which I have to rename. Each folder contain multiple children but I just want to rename the parent. I know it should not have been required in the first place but not I am already in this situation. Renaming them one by one is going to take a long time and I wanted to automate this somehow. Is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by MicahalMa, I used a similar approach and called rename in a loop using c#. Here is my not so elegant code.

```
private static void RenameDirectories()
        {
            string path = @"E:\Local\Development\"; //Path for parent directory

            List<string> directoriesToRename = new List<string>();
            string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            string tfsTool = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe";
            string command = "rename";

            var p = new Process();
            int i = 0;

            foreach (string s in directories)
            {
                i++;

                string param = command + " " + path + "\\" + s + " " + path + "\\" + s.Remove(s.Length - 1);
                Console.WriteLine("Running " + i + " of" + directoriesToRename.Count());
                Console.WriteLine("Renaming started for " + s);
                p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(tfsTool, param)
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false
                };
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
                Console.WriteLine("Renaming Complete for " + s);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------");
                File.AppendAllText(@"c:\log.txt", s + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Be aware that you history will be affected by this.  Folder renames are usually not good in TFS.  If you had branches it's even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Just use command line tf.exe. For just 200 renames, you can just call tf.exe 200 times "tf rename foo bar" and then check all changes in. 
You can also explore powershell option (there are tfs cmdlets). 
Last but not least you can write tfs script - each line is new tf.exe command, but they all share server connection so it's speedier:
script1.tfs
"
rename foo1 bar1
rename foo2 bar2

" and you call tf @script1.tfs (the @ is crucial)
Please remember to create workspace that covers all your folders first and easiest is to call tf.exe from folder that is mapped in it.
Good luck!